# PySpark string to timestamp yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a large notebook which run into a automatic pipeline, it started failing and I found the code which was making it fail (#create timestamp) however I cannot seem to rectify it.

If I take out the create timestamp code it runs but the format of 'CurrentStateDateTime' isn't formatted correctly.

Can any help with this?

[image]

```py
# Create Unique Date time for grouping
df = df.withColumn('CurrentStateDateTime', concat(df.CurrentStateDate,lit(' '),regexp_replace(dfPCN.CurrentStateTime,' ',''),lit(':00')))

# create timestamp
df = df.withColumn('CurrentStateDateTime', F.to_timestamp(df.CurrentStateDateTime,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
```

I am trying to group Date and Time column and create a timestamp as yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from the line that concats the CurrentStateDate column.

For the snapshot you shared, i beleive the below code will work:

```
df = df.withColumn('CurrentStateDate', regexp_replace(df.CurrentStateDate,' ',''))
df = df.withColumn('CurrentStateDate', to_timestamp(df.CurrentStateDate,'dd/MM/yyyy')) 
df.show()
```